# After 5 to 5.1 SQL upgrade 500 internal server error

Tags: mysql, sql, .htaccess

It's on a site that uses symlink - not sure if that's to blame.

I upgraded from SQL 5 to 5.1.

Several sites failed due to the htaccess saying php rather than php5 but that was simple to fix, one site is proving more difficult and I can't seem to find an answer.

The index.php page is actually static html so I'm thinking it must be the .htaccess at fault for this showing a 500 internal server error.

The .htaccess file looks like this:

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(\.cache|images|cgi-bin|ads|css|vids|theme)  -  [L]
RewriteRule SteelExternalAll\.swf$ /theme/skin-SteelExternal.swf [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[^/]+/(play-|index\.)
RewriteRule ^(games|videos|animations)/([^/]+)/?   /$1/play-$2/   [NS,R=permanent,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Comment: Presumably by SQL you mean MySQL? Also what does updating MySQL have to do with .htaccess files? Isn't that Apache? Did you also update PHP? Have you looked at Apache's log file (`/var/log/apache2/error.log` on Ubuntu, not sure where it is on other OS's)?

Comment: The .htaccess is not likely at fault. A 500 error is logged in the Apache error_log. Go look in the error_log to see what is going on! Most likely you have an incompatibility with your application code.

Comment: Thanks guys, I looked at the error logs and it was a SoftException due to files being writable by the group. Do you know a way I can quickly mass change all file permissions from 644 to 600?

Comment: It seems so - thanks to both of you for pointing me in the direction of the error log. I probably seem a fool not looking there in the first place, just until I made a 500.shtml file it was full of a different type of error. Your help was much appreciated :-)